# Unable to pass an object with a scope property to angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass an object that has reference to a controller's scope to the angular directive through property. Basicly object represents some complex model, which is bound to html. My problem is that it gets copied, and when it hits scope it throws exceptions.

I have got plunker example (https://next.plnkr.co/edit/0jCSMhWs6fgDEpMW). The exception (in console) is

```
previewer.41a48d826afff4888855.js:14 Error: [ng:cpws] Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported.
    at VM838 angular.dew.js:144
    at copyElement (VM838 angular.dew.js:1102)
    at copyRecurse (VM838 angular.dew.js:1072)
    at copyElement (VM838 angular.dew.js:1115)
    at copyRecurse (VM838 angular.dew.js:1072)
    at copyElement (VM838 angular.dew.js:1115)
    at copy (VM838 angular.dew.js:1047)
    at Scope.$digest (VM838 angular.dew.js:19294)
    at Scope.$apply (VM838 angular.dew.js:19655)
    at bootstrapApply (VM838 angular.dew.js:1981)
```

Basicly code looks like this

```
import angular from 'angular';
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.directiveModel = {
    name: 'Kappa',
    thatScope: $rootScope
  };
}).directive('some', function (){
  return {
        scope: {
            details: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          element.append(scope.details.someProperty.name);
        }
    };
});
```

Markup

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <p some details='{someProperty: directiveModel}'>Start editing and see your changes reflected here!</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```